# Trying to secure actuator health endpoint giving 403 Forbidden error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to secure actuator health endpoint using spring security:

To achieve this, I have added the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ActuatorSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static final String ACTUATOR_ROLE = System.getenv("actuatorRole");

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
                .hasRole(ACTUATOR_ROLE)
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

The following properties I have defined in my application.properties file:

```
spring.security.user.name=${username}
spring.security.user.password=${actuatorPassword}
spring.security.user.roles=${actuatorRole}
management.endpoint.health.roles=${actuatorRole}
```

But when I am trying to run the health check after this configuration, it is giving me 403 Forbidden error. Can anybody please help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` and see where the 403 is coming from?

Comment: How do you pass username and password? Are you using Postman to test it?

Comment: @Nemanja Yes I am using Postman to pass username and password using Basic Auth.

Comment: Do you have actuorRole enviroment variable defined? Can you verify that role that you have provided in properties file and role that you take from env.variable are same?

Comment: Yes they both are getting picked from same environment variable.

Comment: What are the values for `${username}`, `${actuatorPassword}` and `${actuatorRole}`? For testing replace your env variables with static values.

Comment: Try to disable csrf by setting csrf().disable(). If you ommit this, csrf is enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
application.properties:
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```